# Change the Magento 2 Menu icon font-size

Tags: variables, fonts, less, pseudo-element, magento2

I'm having a go at theming a magento2 shop. I'm not a developer so lots of stuff that might be obvious to seasoned developer are not to me.

I'm trying to change the font-size of the hamburger menu, icon-menu.
I've found the variable responsible for it. But I've not be able to change the font-size to 43px with a _extend.less file.

```
& when (@media-common = true) {
    .nav-toggle {
        .lib-icon-font(
        @icon-menu,
        @_icon-font-size: 28px,
        @_icon-font-color: @header-icons-color,
        @_icon-font-color-hover: @header-icons-color-hover
        );
        .lib-icon-text-hide();
        cursor: pointer;
        display: block;
        font-size: 0;
        left: 15px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 15px;
        z-index: 14;
    }
}

<span data-action="toggle-nav" class="action nav-toggle"><span>Toggle Nav</span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what I did wrong the first 2 times, but I've got it working now.

```
& when (@media-common = true) {
    .nav-toggle {
        .lib-icon-font(
        @icon-menu,
        @_icon-font-size: 43px
        );
    }
}
```